# How to extract translations from a custom vendors bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, translation, symfony5, vendor

I actually trying to create my own reusable bundle. I created a Demo project that include my custom bundle as dependency using symlink composer config.
Actually, I tried to extract some translation keys from my custom bundle into the demo project.
But when I launch the command `bin/console translation:update fr --dump-messages` there is no entry from my bundle.

What I want to extract is some constant keys that I want to translate.
For example, in MyCustomClass there is some status in an array. So I don't know if there is an Interface that I can implement to auto extract my translation keys.

I'm using:

- Symfony Framework 5.3.8
- Symfony Translation 5.3.9

Thanks